# Tried switching to KDE, but certain things look wrong

Tags: themes, kde

I wanted to try KDE, so I logged out, changed to Kubuntu, and logged in. Things are mostly fine, but a handful of things look off. For example, in Firefox, theres a very rigid box surrounding the menu bar that doesn't match up with the default KDE theme. [image: Here's a good example, from the file open dialog I got when trying to post a picture.]

Are things supposed to look like that, or is there something wrong (and how do I fix it?)

Comment: Your titlebar looks okay, but the rest of the window looks like it has reverted to some sort of stock theme. I'm not a KDE user though, so I can't tell you much more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kubuntu is using the kubuntu-firefox-installer /1/ whitch is installing the firefox-kde-support /2/. Without the KDE integration the Firefox is using native (GTK ?) dialogs.

Do you have the firefox-kde-support installed ?

(1) (Kubuntu 11.10) http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/kubuntu-firefox-installer

Description: Mozilla Firefox installer for Kubuntu
Enables easy installation of Mozilla Firefox on Kubuntu, via a graphical user
interface and menu entry.

(2) (Kubuntu 11.10) http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/firefox-kde-support

Description: Integration of Mozilla Firefox with KDE
 This is a helper application that allows Mozilla Firefox to use
 KDE file dialogs, file associations, protocol handlers and
 other KDE integration features.

Very old way: http://kde-look.org/content/show.php?content=13967

Comment: It looks like I did not have either of those packages, so I installed both, closed FF, and re-opened it. It doesn't look any different so far. Is there anything else I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

You could try changing your GTK+ themes in 
System Settings>Application Appearance>GTK+ Appearance.

It could be, that by using gnome, it automatically synced to the Raleigh (gnome) theme, to make your gnome experience better. (even linus torvalds thinks that gnome 3 is a complete clusterfuck.) you should switch back to oxygen-gtk

fixing it will be much easier for a linux noob than reinstalling firefox, which might not do anything

Comment: +1 This was a simple fix that worked